# function to iterate over different values

Tags: python, dataframe

hello I have a lot of dataframes of this type to process (with several columns of the same name)

I want to perform a sort (method) that allows me to enter "name" as many times as the value assigned to it in order to obtain this type of datafames. Anyone have an idea please? thank you in advance for your answers

I have :

```
    name    value   value   value
    0       blabla1 blabla2 blabla3
    1       1       10      100
    2       2       20      200
    3       3       30      300
```

I wish to have :

```
    name    value
0   blabla1 1
1   blabla1 2
2   blabla1 3
3   blabla2 10
4   blabla2 20
5   blabla2 30
6   blabla3 100
7   blabla3 200
8   blabla3 300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Henry's solution works well. Here's another approach that you could have taken. In the future, try to look at some cheat sheets like this one: https://pandas.pydata.org/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Declare df to be the array of interest

df = pd.DataFrame(
  [["blabla1", "blabla2", "blabla3"], 
  [1, 10, 100], [2, 20, 200], 
  [3, 30, 300]], 
  columns=['value', 'value', 'value']
).rename_axis('name')

# Go ahead and transpose it so we can use a 'melt' function easily

print(df.transpose())

# name         0    1    2    3
# value  blabla1    1    2    3
# value  blabla2   10   20   30
# value  blabla3  100  200  300

################################

# Melt the values that are not in 0 column into a single 'value' column
print(df.transpose().melt(id_vars = 0))

#          0 name value
# 0  blabla1    1     1
# 1  blabla2    1    10
# 2  blabla3    1   100
# 3  blabla1    2     2
# 4  blabla2    2    20
# 5  blabla3    2   200
# 6  blabla1    3     3
# 7  blabla2    3    30
# 8  blabla3    3   300

################################

# Just some finish touches, like column renaming, sorting, etc.
print(
  df.transpose()\
    .melt(id_vars = 0)\
    .drop(columns = ['name'])\
    .rename({0: 'name'}, axis='columns')\
    .sort_values(by = 'name')\
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

#       name value
# 0  blabla1     1
# 1  blabla1     2
# 2  blabla1     3
# 3  blabla2    10
# 4  blabla2    20
# 5  blabla2    30
# 6  blabla3   100
# 7  blabla3   200
# 8  blabla3   300
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC try [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html#pandas-melt):

```
import pandas as pd

# re-create data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[0, "blabla1", "blabla2", "blabla3"],
     [1, 1, 10, 100], [2, 2, 20, 200],
     [3, 3, 30, 300]],
    columns=['name', 'value', 'value', 'value']
)
# End re-create data

# Get Rid of current name column
df = df.drop(columns='name')
# Set Columns to the first row of the dataframe
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
# Rename axis, drop the first row of dataframe and melt
df = df.rename_axis('name', axis=1).iloc[1:].melt()

print(df)
```

Output:

```
      name value
0  blabla1     1
1  blabla1     2
2  blabla1     3
3  blabla2    10
4  blabla2    20
5  blabla2    30
6  blabla3   100
7  blabla3   200
8  blabla3   300
```

Comment: Henry, its perfect! Thanks a lot for your answer